# I'm about to upgrade to 12.04 from 11.10. What should I backup before hand?

Tags: upgrade

Just like the title says. I Have already backed up my home folder. Is there anything in /etc/ or /usr/share I should back up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly. If there are any applications present on your system of which you want to back-up the configuration files, you should.

Upgrades seldomly result in data loss, as no manipulation to the partitions is done.

Answer (score 0):

You should backup everything.  This is just a general principal, and has nothing in particular to do with the 11.10 -> 12.04 upgrade.  I didn't have any issues when I upgraded my machine.  I recommend backing up everything just to be "safe rather than sorry".